# How to generate AWS Cognito Bearer token in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, authentication, jmeter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We use Amazon Cognito authentication with the AWS Amplified Framework in our application. Now I want to do a JMeter performance test. How do I create an AWS Cognito Bearer Token on JMeter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your "AWS Amplified Framework" is, however it might be sufficient just to send a single simple [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request to the [TOKEN ENDPOINT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) providing relevant `grant_type`, `client_id`, `code`, etc. parameters.

User credentials can be supplied via [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter/) so you won't have to encode them into Base64 yourself and add the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header